# How to get the count of similar columns from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns id and value. I want to select the records where there exist other records in the same value with a lower id but the same value. I need the count of these. For example, if I have this table

```
id | value
---+------
 1 |   1
 2 |   2
 3 |   1  
 4 |   3
 5 |   2
 6 |   1
```

I need the answer

```
id | value | count
---+-------+------
 3 |   1   |  1      // 1 other row with value 1 and a lower id
 5 |   2   |  1      // 1 other row with value 2 and a lower id
 6 |   1   |  2      // 2 other rows with value 1 and a lower id.
```

I can get the first two columns by doing

```
select id as id1, value as value1 from table where exists
(select id as id2, value as value2 from table
where value2 = value1 and id1 < id2);
```

However I can't work out how to get the count. Should I use `having` or `group by` to get the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by id) - 1 as prev_values
      from t
     ) t
where prev_values > 0;
```